# Plot a certain day range for histogram R

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram, posixlt

I have more than thousands of data with posixt format.

```
eg:"Tue Feb 11 14:17:41 +0000 2014"
```

The data spans from february 11 to february 16. 
I want to plot a histogram that plots only the data on february 15.
I've tried

```
hist(newtime, "hours",plot = TRUE, freq = FALSE,
 main = "Histogram for 14",
 format="%d", right = TRUE)
```

but I don't know how to choose the data on february 15th only

Comment: can you give us a sample dataframe? that helps us give the right answer.

Comment: You can use `[` to subset data in a vector. Like `newtime[format(newtime, "%Y-%m-%d") == "2018-02-16")]`. Just give the subset you want to plot to `hist`.

Comment: it looked something like this [596] "Tue Feb 11 16:25:09 +0000 2014"
 [597] "Tue Feb 11 16:25:13 +0000 2014"
 [598] "Tue Feb 11 16:26:32 +0000 2014"
 [599] "Tue Feb 11 16:26:43 +0000 2014"
 [600] "Tue Feb 11 16:27:26 +0000 2014"
 [601] "Tue Feb 11 16:28:08 +0000 2014"
 [602] "Tue Feb 11 16:28:29 +0000 2014"
 [603] "Tue Feb 11 16:28:32 +0000 2014"
 [604] "Tue Feb 11 16:29:11 +0000 2014"
 [605] "Tue Feb 11 16:29:33 +0000 2014"
 [606] "Tue Feb 11 16:30:03 +0000 2014"
 [607] "Tue Feb 11 16:30:22 +0000 2014"
 [608] "Tue Feb 11 16:31:22 +0000 2014"